# ReferenceError: "productfancybox is not defined" at onClick event

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, nopcommerce

I am trying to display products in fancybox on href link `onClick` event.
but when click event occures, it gives an error like

> ReferenceError: productfancybox is not defined

I have tried this code:

HomePageProducts.cshtml:

```
<div class="herry-pic-cols brdr">
            <ul id="homePageFeaturedProductInit">
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <li>
                        <span id="@item.Id">
                           @Html.Partial("_CategoryBox", item)
                           <a id="Link" href="#" onClick ="productfancybox(@item.Id);">Link</a>
                        </span>
                    </li>    
                }
            </ul>

            <div class="clear"></div>
            <a class="prev-btn2" href="#"></a>
            <a class="next-btn2" href="#"></a>
        </div>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(window).load(function () {

            function productfancybox(id) {

                $.fancybox({
                    'width': '80%',
                    'height': '100%',
                    'autoScale': true,
                    'transitionIn': 'fade',
                    'transitionOut': 'fade',
                    'href': '/Category/CategoryProductsFancyBox?Id='+id,
                    'type': 'iframe',
                    'onClosed': function () {
                        window.location.href = "f?p=&APP_ID.:211:&SESSION.::&DEBUG.::";
                    }
                });

            }

        });
        </script>
```

Why `onClick` event is not working?
Am i missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function, `productfancybox` is scoped locally to the anonymous function called on window load. Once that occurs, it goes away and no longer exists.

Instead, you need to define your function in the global namespace (i.e. *not* inside a call like this), or and preferably, create a namespace and define your function there:

```
var MyAwesomeNamespace = MyAwesomeNamespace || {};

MyAwesomeNamespace.productfancybox = function (id) {
    ...
}
```

Then later, you can call:

```
MyAwesomeNamespace.productfancybox(1);
```

Anywhere in your code, after that script has run. This is just a simple example. There's better ways to set up a library for your application. Here's a basic primer you can work from: http://css-tricks.com/how-do-you-structure-javascript-the-module-pattern-edition/.